# Separating addition terms in denominator

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, partial-fractions

If I have a fraction such as:

$\frac{1+d(6-4a)}{1-a+d(7-4a)}$

then how can I separate it so I have it as $\frac{1}{1-a}+(some-term)$

Thanks.

Comment: HINT: $\frac{1+d(6-4a)}{1-a+d(7-4a)}=\frac{1}{1-a}+q \mbox{ }$ 
find $q$.

Comment: @Skills, the denominator of the original expression is $1 - a + d(7 - 4a)$.  Following your hint, the denominator of the RHS is just $1 - a$.  Or perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: If I actually subtract $\frac{1}{1-a}$ from the LHS, I think I should get q which is what I would need to add to $\frac{1}{1-a}$. I'm trying this as I type.

Comment: He wants $\frac{1}{1-a} + $ (some term) so
$\frac{1+d(6-4a)}{1-a+d(7-4a)}=\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{d(4a^2 - 6a - 1)}{(a - 1)(a(4·d + 1) - 7d - 1)}$ @JoseArnaldoDris

Comment: Yes, I think your method works, @Skills

Comment: @Skills, you should write that out as an answer.  =)

Comment: I did it @JoseArnaldoDris =)

Answer (score 5):

I write what i wrote in a comment.

You want $\frac{1+d(6−4a)}{1−a+d(7−4a)}=\frac{1}{1-a}+q$

so $q=\frac{1+d(6−4a)}{1−a+d(7−4a)}-\frac{1}{1-a}=\frac{d(4a^2−6a−1)}{(a−1)(a(4⋅d+1)−7d−1)}$

ergo

$$\frac{1+d(6−4a)}{1−a+d(7−4a)}=\frac{1}{1-a}+\frac{d(4a^2−6a−1)}{(a−1)(a(4d+1)−7d−1)}$$

Answer (score 0):

You initially have the fraction

$$\frac{1 + d(6 - 4a)}{1 - a + d(7 - 4a)}.$$

You can rewrite this as:

$$\frac{1 - d + d(7 - 4a)}{1 - a + d(7 - 4a)}.$$

Furthermore, you can rewrite the last expression as:

$$\frac{(a - d) + (1 - a + d(7 - 4a))}{1 - a + d(7 - 4a)}$$

which simplifies to

$$1 + \frac{a - d}{1 - a + d(7 - 4a)}.$$

Without further information about the allowable values for $d$ (or perhaps, a relationship between $a$ and $d$), I don't think this last quantity can be further streamlined to suit your purposes.

What sort of simplification did you have in mind?

Comment: I think since I need the answer in term of $\frac{1}{1-a}$ form, it might be better for me to try $\frac{1}{1-a}+q$ like @Skills mentioned and find q from subtracting $\frac{1}{1-a}$ from the other expression. I'm trying that.

Comment: You can try Skills' suggestion.  Haven't checked at length from my end, though.